# who controls a linux service?

Tags: services

How do I quickly find out who controls some linux service?

I'm tired of poking around /etc to find out if initd, upstart, systemd or supervisord is controlling some service.

Comment: When you find yourself doing the same task repeatedly on a computer, write a program (shell script) to do it for you. And yes, the profusion of service managers is obnoxious but I don't see it getting better anytime soon.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not sure which init, you can guess from `ps | grep -E "systemd|upstart"`.  (Some shiny systemd may be present on legacy upstart systems, but not vice-versa I think).  You can check for supervisord or so as well.

Googling initd tells me about `/etc/init.d` so I assume that's what you meant...  Sorry but nothing comes to mind for detecting sysV init-scripts *other* than looking in /etc.  (If you're stuck on sysvinit I guess you *additionally* want to `/etc/init.d/foo status` or `service foo status`, to make sure your service is actually being run from sysvinit.  That won't tell you if the service has unfortunately been run from *both* sysvinit and supervisord).

On upstart I think it's easy to find jobs because `initctl list` shows pids.  So if it's there, it's either an upstart job or sysV init-script running under backwards compatibility (and see above to detect the difference).

On systemd you could check for a given pid using [cgroups field of ps](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-for-admins-2.html), see below.  If the cgroup says `.service` it must have been started by systemd.  If you don't mind looking for a (potentially ambiguous) process *name* instead, `systemd-cgls` is easier to remember.  Then I think `systemctl status foo` will even give you enough information to detect sysV init-script for foo.service.

> ```
> $ ps xawf -eo pid,user,cgroup,args
>   PID USER     CGROUP                              COMMAND
>     2 root     -                                   [kthreadd]
>     3 root     -                                    \_ [ksoftirqd/0]
> [...]
>  4281 root     -                                    \_ [flush-8:0]
>     1 root     name=systemd:/systemd-1             /sbin/init
>   455 root     name=systemd:/systemd-1/sysinit.service /sbin/udevd -d
> 28188 root     name=systemd:/systemd-1/sysinit.service  \_ /sbin/udevd -d
> 28191 root     name=systemd:/systemd-1/sysinit.service  \_ /sbin/udevd -d
>  1096 dbus     name=systemd:/systemd-1/dbus.service /bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --systemd-activation
> [...]
> ```

For supervisord use `supervisord status`.